# Automatic Website Login, Long URLs, Encryption

Tags: asp.net, url, encryption, rsa

I'm building a secure payment portal.

We currently have two applications that will be using this.  One is a web application, the other a desktop app. Both of these require users to login/authenticate, the same credentials can be used for either application.

I want to build an automatic login mechanism that will fill in all the various login/order details and be able to call this from either app mentioned above.  I've been thinking that the best way to do this is to pass this information encrypted through the URL. ie https://mysite.com/TakePayment.aspx?id=GT2jkjh3....

Since we don't want to integrate the payment processing too tightly into the desktop app to reduce our PCI scope, we decided to have it open the browser to a central, secured payment page through a simple shell execute with the full URL causing the default browser to open that page.

Originally we were using AES for the encryption, but this is currently being re-examined as we would prefer not having to give out the key to the end user (AES is symmetric, symmetric encryption = both parties need the private key, why bother even encrypting then since we're going to be distributing the app?)  So I'm looking at switching it over to use Public Key Encryption with the built in RSA routines within .NET

After coding up the RSA portion I noticed most examples on the net used 1024bits for the key-length, I went with this and now have our portal working with public key encryption, however the URLs generated are much much longer than when I was using AES so it made me start researching what the max limits for URLs are.  http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html Says that IE is the limiting browser at about 2048 characters in the path portion.  My initial tests with the RSA encryption show my urls will be around 1400 chars long.

My questions boil down to this:

1) Is there a better way for passing information from a desktop app to a website that I'm not thinking of?  I'd prefer it be just as easy to use from another web page as it is from the desktop, hence my current solution.

2) Is 1024 bit RSA keys necessary? Or overkill for something like this? A shorter key would mean shorter encrypted text right?

3) Are there any other unforeseen problems with URLs in the 1200-1400 character range?  Proxies? Firewalls? Web-Accelerators?

Thanks

**Update 12/11/2011:**
Come to find out, the method that we ended up going with here ended up biting us in the ass recently (or rather we found out about it today, even though the problem was a very sporadic and difficult one to track down..)

The plain text token that we encrypted was originally rather small, only a hundred bytes or so.  This is what resulted in my test URLs being approximately 1400 bytes long.  Through feature creep we've been required to add more data to the token, and the average URL length jumped to 1700-1800 in length.

Once the length of our plain text hits 173 characters long and above however, the URL length jumps again, this time up to 2080+ or so, which now causes problems for IE.  After some investigation in how RSA encryption works, this should have been totally expected, but was an oversight on my part originally.

We're using 1024 bit RSA encryption, which means that the maximum data block size that can be encrypted is 1024/8 - 24 = 86 bytes, every 86 bytes needs to be "chopped up" and encrypted separately, so at 86 * 2  = 172, we're only encrypting two blocks, above that we're encrypting three, four, five, etc. By passing 172, our cipher text length grew so long the URL's are now too long..  I'm probably messing up the explanation a little here, but that's the general gist of it..

It seems we'll be looking at designing a better way for this to work, as it can be expected they'll want "more features" to be added in the future and thus our token will grow ever larger...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all logged in a database can you not pass the data back and forth using SSL web services. Then in the case of being able to quickly go from the desktop app to the web app make a rpc call to the website to generate a random key, pass that to the user and call a web page using that. Make the key valid for say 10 seconds meaning should a key be captured and broken it will have become invalid?

I have little experience with this kind of thing so I'm expecting many holes to be poked in the idea.

Comment: I was thinking the backend db might be a possible work around, except the apps currently do not share a central db, and I'd prefer to keep the desktop/web app accessing the payment portals db to an absolute minimum.  I might end up going with this route, though.  Timeouts on the key are a good idea, and already implemented (if they try to use an encrypted value outside a certain time window the website rejects the attempt)